# How to duplicate a JsonNode / JsonObject / JsonArray?

Tags: c#, .net-core, jsonnode

The new mutable `JsonNode` type has neither a `Clone()` nor a copy-constructor. How can I make a copy of one?

I tried to duplicate a *shallow* `JsonObject` (one filled with primitive key-value pairs) using `new JsonObject(original)`, but even this doesn't work (it throws `InvalidOperationException` because a `JsonNode` cannot be shared between two JSON trees).

Answer (score 2):

You can clone it indirectly by converting it to JSON, and converting it back to `JsonNode`.

The quick & dirty way:

```
var copy = JsonNode.Parse(original.ToJsonString());
```

It should be noted that JsonNode reads and writes JSON in UTF-8 format, so this method is inefficient partly because it'll convert to UTF-16 and back (and partly because it's parsing, which we seemingly can't avoid). Here is a more efficient method:

```cs
public static JsonNode? Clone(this JsonNode? node) {
    if (node == null)
        return null;

    // Yes, we're creating three garbage objects (array + two writers) but
    // the alternative `JsonNode.Parse(original.ToJsonString())` is worse.
    var buf = new ArrayBufferWriter<byte>(512);
    var jwriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(buf);
    node.WriteTo(jwriter);
    jwriter.Flush(); // I don't know why this is necessary, but it is
    return JsonNode.Parse(buf.WrittenSpan);
}

[return: NotNullIfNotNull("node")]
public static JsonObject? Clone(this JsonObject? node)
    => (JsonObject?) Clone((JsonNode) node);

[return: NotNullIfNotNull("node")]
public static JsonArray? Clone(this JsonArray? node)
    => (JsonArray?) Clone((JsonNode)node);
```

(this does lack an array-pooling optimization used by `ToJsonString`, which relies on an internal class we don't have access to. It's still better.)

---

Unit test:

```cs
[Test]
public void JsonNodeCloneTest()
{
    var json = JsonNode.Parse(@"{
        ""A"": 12345.67890,
        ""B"": [ ""string"", false, true, null, { ""N"": ""no"" } ]
    }")!;
    var jsonString1 = json.ToJsonString();
            
    var json2 = json.Clone(); // method under test
            
    var jsonString2 = json2.ToJsonString();

    Assert.AreEqual(jsonString1, jsonString2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Note:  my solution is in JAVA

I have copied my "valueNode" during iteration and made a copy of it using ObjectMapper now "copyJsonNode" is the replica of "valueNode" which i need for further implementation.

```
if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {

            JsonNode valueNode = entry.getValue();
            
            String copyjson = valueNode.toString();

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            JsonNode copyJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(copyjson);

           ....}
```